# Why my png function appear to not create any image?

Tags: php, image, png, watermark

I am trying to create a png watermark from text input. I use same function for jpeg and everything works perfectly fine.

I use imagestring(). In the code below I try to make two images, one of them is watermark and second one is resized dafault image.

I uplode photos through my form and they correctly appear in the default photos folder. None of the functions below return an image.

$destination_w is a path to the folder with watermarks. $destination_m is a path to the folder with miniatures. $_SESSION['mime'] and $_SESSION['image'] store correct values as I have tried to var_dump them and they appear in html which is rendered after this functions. Problem is that images do not exist, so they are not visible on my page.

This function is stored in watermark.inc.php file which is included after saving the photos to the default folder and their info in database.

```
else if ($_SESSION['mime'] === 'image/png'){ 
$img = imagecreatefrompng($source.'/'.$_SESSION['image']);
$blackcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($img, 3,15, 30, $_SESSION['watermark'], $blackcolor); 
imagepng($img, $destination_w.'/'.$_SESSION['image'], 100); 
imagedestroy($img); 

$img = imagecreatefrompng($source.'/'.$_SESSION['image']);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source.'/'.$_SESSION['image']);

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 125);

//MINIATURES
imagecopyresized($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 125, $width, $height);
imagepng($thumb, $destination_m.'/'.$_SESSION['image'], 100); 
imagedestroy($img);
imagedestroy($thumb);
```

};

Comment: Welcome zuzqqa - Please read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Don't post code as an image but directly.

Comment: Can you add some details please? 
Do you get an error message? What and how did you debug your code?
If you var_dump $img - is it the desired object. And does it change after you apply imagestring

Comment: I copied function to be in the file after storing default photos. When I try to var_dump() $img it is not working. I could be doing something wrong tho. It just stops the if function and then redirect the view, which is in my return.

Comment: Wait, I have an idea how to check this. I know what I did wrong.

Comment: Okey, so when I var_dump($img) i get "resource(7) of type (gd)" which is right, I suppose. I do not have long experience with php.

Comment: var_dump($img) after imagestring gets "resource(8) of type (gd)"

Comment: Alright, I solved it. I had no idea, that the quality range for the ImagePNG function is from 0 to 9. I put 100 in my code, same as in JPEG. That has solved my problem. Watermarks are good now.

Comment: Nice to hear. You can answer your own question and if other people find it, it might help them.